# uploading file to django from iphone form.is_valid() failed

Tags: iphone, django, asiformdatarequest

I am trying to upload image to django from iphone with ASIFormDataRequest.

in my django views.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    file = forms.FileField()

@csrf_exempt
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid(): ##this is always fail
                newimage = Image(imgfile = request.FILES['image'])
                newimage.save()

                return HttpResponse('succeeded')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('failed')
```

in models.py

```
 class Image(models.Model):
         imgfile = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
```

i got this in settings.py

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/www/media'
```

with the above code, i can't get the form validated, but if i remove form.is_valid(), then the image is successfully uploaded to /srv/www/media/images/

and the following is the iOS code:

```
formRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[formRequest setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
formRequest.delegate = self;
[formRequest setData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f) withFileName:fileName andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"image"];
[formRequest setPostValue:userName forKey:@"name"];
[formRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[formRequest setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
[formRequest startAsynchronous];
```

please, any suggestion is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: if your form doesnt validate, you can normally rerender the form and look at the thrown error message. You will have to adapt your view to this. Have a look here for further information on Forms and Validation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about iOS, but looks to me that you're providing a value for key `name`, but you don't have that field in your form - you have `jid` instead. Since that field is required, and you're not providing it, the form is not valid.

Comment: sorry for my typo, the "jid" = "name", i already changed it, but the problem still here.

Comment: ohh... you are right, the typo. thanks a lot. i now know that i need to have the same names in the form field with the names in the form i submitted. thanks a lot.